# Functions and Structures Versus Classes

Tags: c++

I'm working on writing a small card game in C++ as practice. I'm using a structure to represent individual cards:

```
#include <string>
struct card
{
    int number;
    std::string suit;
};
```

Cards will be held in a deck, for which I'll define a function--say, `draw_card`--that removes `x` cards from the bottom of the deck, with a default of one. I figured I can implement this in two ways:

**As a structure:**

```
#include <vector>
struct deck
{
    std::vector<card> cards_left
};

void draw_card(std::vector<card>& deck, int cards_to_draw = 1) {
// This function takes a deck by reference and removes cards_to_draw from the bottom.
};
```

**As a class:**

```
class deck
{
    std::vector<card> cards_left;
public:
    void draw_card(int cards_to_draw = 1);
};

void deck::draw_card(int cards_to_draw = 1)
{
// This function takes cards_left and removes cards_to_draw from the bottom.
}
```

I could write a similar function (in both cases) to populate `cards_left` in both the class and the structure. For problems like these, why should I prefer using the class over the structure? Is it strictly a question of organizing all functions that only apply to a given class together, or are there additional advantages?

Comment: There is no real difference between a class and a struct. Using one over the other is all down to convention, of which there are many. So that question is opinion based.

Comment: You tend to think that having a method is tied to declare as a class. Your question here is not structure or class, it is method or free function. Here you should not expose the internals of the Deck and provide methods to manipulate the Deck. So OOP is clearly in favor of what you call "class"

Answer (score 2):

The difference between class and struct is the default protection of the attributes (both data and method).

For example:

```
class deck
{
    std::vector<card> cards_left;
public:
    void draw_card(int cards_to_draw = 1);
};
```

works the same as:

```
struct deck
{
private:
    std::vector<card> cards_left;
public:
    void draw_card(int cards_to_draw = 1);
};
```